# Python's timedelta doesn't work on database records unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: datetime.datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I need to compare two timestamps from a database. First I save one record as a dictionary, then another one, then compare the datetime components from those dictionaries and get this error message:

> TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: datetime.datetime

The relevant code is:

```
import datetime
# got records from database, then fromated dictionary:
record_1 = {'timestamp': timestamp, 'x': x, 'y': y}
# latter on
record_2 = record_1
record_1 = {'timestamp': timestamp, 'x': x, 'y': y}
# Records prints:
# {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 21, 6, 47, 38), 'x': 1, 'y': 2}
# {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 16, 21, 59, 59), 'x': 3, 'y': 4}
# Respectively, error ocures in line:
difference = datetime.timedelta(record_1['timestamp'], record_2['timestamp'])
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To compare two `datetime.datime` objects you only need to do a subtraction like:

```
difference = record_1['timestamp'] - record_2['timestamp']
```

This will result in a:

```
datetime.timedelta
```

object.

Comment: @KestutisStugys, you are very welcome.  However, on SO the very best way to say thanks is to upvote *any* questions or answers you find useful.  And on your questions, if one of the answers is a good fit for your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer.  See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for guidelines.